# Summing time series data

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I have time based per minute data and would like to sum it into hourly (or other periods such as week,month).

The data looks like this

```
timeStamp,kwH,watts
"2016-07-16 16:18:51",0.014,710
"2016-07-16 16:20:01",0.013,669
"2016-07-16 16:22:40",0.020,720
...
"2016-07-16 21:06:01",0.006,360
"2016-07-16 21:07:00",0.006,366
"2016-07-16 21:08:01",0.007,413
"2016-07-16 21:09:01",0.006,360
```

I'm wanting to sum the second column (kwH) grouped by the hour on column 1.

A larger dataset is available from http://pastebin.com/raw/BbjLebVx

How do I go about summing this? I'm guessing it may involve awk.

Secondly, given that the data, web service and bash script generating the graphs all reside on a server I control, is it more efficient for me to sum this data in mySQL rather than try to get gnuplot to deal with megabytes of raw data?

Comment: [edit] your question to get rid of the `...`s cluttering up your input file so we have something concrete to test a potential solution against, and also to provide the expected output given that input.

Comment: This is a classical histogram/binning task which can be easily done with gnuplot only. If you are still interested in a solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > test.awk
{
  gsub(/^.* |:.*/,"",$1); # using regex remove all but the hour from the timestamp for "grouping by the hour" 
  arr[$1]+=$2             # sum together the "kwH"
} 
END {                     # after summing we print
  for (i in arr)          # for each element (hour) in the array
    print i,arr[i]}       # print the element and the sum of "kwH"
$ awk -f test.awk test.in
timeStamp 0
21 0.025
... 0
16 0.047
```